# C++ std::chrono::high_resolution_clock time_since_epoch returns too small numbers. How can I get the correct time since 1970 in microseconds?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I am trying to write a function, which will return the current time in microseconds since 1970. While a debugging I noticed, that the returned numbers are too small. For example: `269104616249`. I also added static_assert to check the returned value type is int64_t, which i big enough to hold `292471` years in microseconds. So integer overflow should not be a case here.
What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code:

```
int64_t NowInMicroseconds() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(duration_cast<microseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count()), int64_t>::value);
    return duration_cast<microseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
}

int64_t result = NowInMicroseconds();
```

Comment: I've checked the maximum value of int64_t is 9223372036854775807, which is enough to hold 292471 years in microseconds.

Comment: I get `1629804220239351` [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c7405ccc1c8f6ca).  Can we get a [mre]?

Comment: @NathanOliver isn't this also just about 5 years?

Comment: The minimum reproducible example is just calling the function NowInMicroseconds

Comment: @user32434999 I get approx 51 years with that value.  Looks like you might be off by a factor of 10

Comment: @NathanOliver I most certainly am :) Sorry

Comment: Note: `high_resolution_clock` is not suitable for monotonic time or the time from 1970. Because it is not monotonic. If you need that you need to use `system_clock`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three chrono-supplied clocks in C++11/14/17 (more in C++20):

1. `system_clock`:  This measures [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (time since 1970 excluding leap seconds).<sup>1</sup>
2. `steady_clock`:  Like a stop-watch.  Great for timing, but it can not tell you the time of day.
3. `high_resolution_clock`:  This has the disadvantages of `system_clock` and `steady_clock`, and the advantages of neither.  Typically it is a type alias to either `system_clock` or `steady_clock`, and which one differs with platform.

You have to use `system_clock` for measuring time since 1970.  Note that this is measured in UTC, *not* your *local* time zone.  In C++11/14/17 to get the local time since 1970, you will have to either manually take your time zone into account, or use this [C++20 chrono preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

```
std::int64_t
NowInMicroseconds()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return duration_cast<microseconds>(system_clock_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
}
```

Consider returning a strong type which means "microseconds since 1970" instead of an integral type.  Strong type safety helps you find your logic errors at compile time:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::microseconds>
NowInMicroseconds()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return time_point_cast<microseconds>(system_clock.now());
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This is unspecified in C++11/14/17, but is true on all implementations.  [C++20 finally nails this epoch down in the spec.](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.system#overview-1)